# Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.2.183:5000/: dial tcp 10.244.2.183:5000: connect: connection refused Back-off restarting failed container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy my application by using Gitlab-CI through pushing the docker images on Azure container and from there deploying the images on azure kubernetes service. these all process is happening automatically through GitlabCI. but i'm facing challenge in deployment section. i can able to see the services, pods is running status also tiller is deployed on kubernetes but it is throwing the below error[image] This is deployment YAML which i took from kubernetes

```
{
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "review-37-in-cust-iosa7i",
    "namespace": "XYZ",
    "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/XYZ/deployments/review-37-in-cust-iosa7i",
    "uid": "9f5f7fff-9d65-11e9-8ceb-0e7a6fb80992",
    "resourceVersion": "7143337",
    "generation": 1,
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-07-03T07:39:00Z",
    "labels": {
      "app": "review-37-in-cust-iosa7i",
      "chart": "auto-deploy-app-0.2.9",
      "heritage": "Tiller",
      "release": "review-37-in-cust-iosa7i",
      "tier": "web",
      "track": "stable"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "1"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "app": "review-37-in-cust-iosa7i",
        "release": "review-37-in-cust-iosa7i",
        "tier": "web",
        "track": "stable"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "app": "review-37-in-cust-iosa7i",
          "release": "review-37-in-cust-iosa7i",
          "tier": "web",
          "track": "stable"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "checksum/application-secrets": ""
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "auto-deploy-app",
            "image": "stratuscentcrdeve.azurecr.io/XYZ/dev/37-in-customer-group-customer-form-when-admin-opens-up-the-poli:65d2e2bc554242c584d5c6480e172690659ef98b",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "web",
                "containerPort": 5000,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "DATABASE_URL",
                "value": "postgres://user:testing-password@review-37-in-cust-iosa7i-postgres:5432/review-37-in-cust-iosa7i"
              }
            ],
            "resources": {},
            "livenessProbe": {
              "httpGet": {
                "path": "/",
                "port": 5000,
                "scheme": "HTTP"
              },
              "initialDelaySeconds": 15,
              "timeoutSeconds": 15,
              "periodSeconds": 10,
              "successThreshold": 1,
              "failureThreshold": 3
            },
            "readinessProbe": {
              "httpGet": {
                "path": "/",
                "port": 5000,
                "scheme": "HTTP"
              },
              "initialDelaySeconds": 5,
              "timeoutSeconds": 3,
              "periodSeconds": 10,
              "successThreshold": 1,
              "failureThreshold": 3
            },
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "securityContext": {},
        "imagePullSecrets": [
          {
            "name": "gitlab-registry"
          }
        ],
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    },
    "strategy": {
      "type": "RollingUpdate",
      "rollingUpdate": {
        "maxUnavailable": 1,
        "maxSurge": 1
      }
    },
    "revisionHistoryLimit": 2147483647,
    "progressDeadlineSeconds": 2147483647
  },
  "status": {
    "observedGeneration": 1,
    "replicas": 1,
    "updatedReplicas": 1,
    "unavailableReplicas": 1,
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "Available",
        "status": "True",
        "lastUpdateTime": "2019-07-03T07:39:00Z",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2019-07-03T07:39:00Z",
        "reason": "MinimumReplicasAvailable",
        "message": "Deployment has minimum availability."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please comment if any additional info is required?

Comment: I understand that the pod is running and you are able to access the application via service. Just the readiness probe is failing. Right? Share the URL you use to access the application. You can add the same context path to the readiness probe settings.

Comment: @suresh- thanks for your input but i can see the external url. because the external url/ip is not yet generated.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error? such the status of the pod and the service to the deployment? and some event.

Comment: @CharlesXu Please find the details on below- [![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5G6T.png

Comment: i dont have the deployment yaml file. i'm very new in gitlab CI. Please suggest me too if any thing im missing. or you need any other details too?

Comment: You need to run the command `kubectl describe pod pod_name` and give the output. The picture does not show the details.

Comment: Where i need to run above command? i am using gitlab CI to build, test, create the docker image, push into the container and then deploy into the kubernetes. i need to run this command in my gitlab-ci.yml file?

Comment: This issue got fixed by changing the expose port from 8081 to 5000. Thanks guys for your inputs.